# Use asp:TemplateField at any position of a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which populates from database with autogenerated column True.I have two columns which are asp:TemplateField column 1,2. grid binds with 4 columns .how can i use a templefield at 5th position .I mean first 2 asp:TemplateField then 2 columns of grid then again a asp:TemplateField  then rest 2 columns.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCycleStats" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="columnheaderLightBlue"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="infoarea" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="gvCycleStats_PageIndexChanged"
    OnRowDataBound="gvCycleStats_OnRowDataBound" EmptyDataText="No work items to display."
    EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="infoarea">
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></RowStyle>
    <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="infoarea" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img id="imgDetails" alt="Images" title="Click to view details" src="images/details-icon.gif"
                    onclick='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID", "javascript:return SetId(\"{0}\");")%> ' />
                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSelect" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID", "javascript:return SetId(\"{0}\");")%>'Text="Select" />--%>
                <%--OnClientClick="javascript:window.showModalDialog('ViewSelect.aspx?Id='" + id + " + "&windowTitle=" + " + windowtitle + " ', '', 'dialogHeight:700px;dialogWidth:1000px');return false;"/>--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderTemplate>
                DETAILS
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img id="imgDetails" alt="Images" title="Click to view audit details" src="images/details-icon.gif" onclick='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID", "javascript:return SetAuditIdId(\"{0}\");")%> ' />
                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSelect" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID", "javascript:return SetId(\"{0}\");")%>'Text="Select" />--%>
                <%--OnClientClick="javascript:window.showModalDialog('ViewSelect.aspx?Id='" + id + " + "&windowTitle=" + " + windowtitle + " ', '', 'dialogHeight:700px;dialogWidth:1000px');return false;"/>--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderTemplate>
                AUDIT DETAILS
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="columnheaderLightBlue" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="infoarea" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont bind it as autogenerate columns = true,

for those columns use simple bound field and then after use template field